# Unknown errors in makefile in Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I did some changes like copying .dll (libmysql.dll) in project directories, and included include and libs path in mysql.pro. So now when I debug any program I get some error as follows:

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. jom:
>   D:\qt_projects\build-zerocopy-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug
>   [debug\main.obj] Error 1

> 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. jom:
>   D:\qt_projects\build-zerocopy-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug
>   [debug\client.obj] Error 1 jom:
>   D:\qt_projects\build-zerocopy-Desktop_Qt_5_0_2_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\Makefile
>   [debug] Error 2 10:48:01: The process
>   "D:\QT\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2. Error while
>   building/deploying project zerocopy (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.2 MSVC2010
>   32bit) When executing step 'Make' 10:48:01: Elapsed time: 00:01.

Is this error because of those changes? I am running a totally different program i.e I haven't included any sql header or anything. Please help me out.

Comment: The problem is that Qt Creator tries compiling with the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler (MSVC), but it doesn't find the cl.exe which is used for compiling. Do you have MSVC installed?

Comment: @TimMeyer : yes it is installed

Comment: yeah got the same problem some time ago when compiling the sqldrivers from the terminal. you have to tell qt where to find the cl.exe (add to $(PATH) or to use the visual studio command prompt.

Comment: In your `Tools->Options->Build&Run->Tool Chains` Window in Qt Creator, is MSVC listed under "Auto detected"?

Comment: @TimMeyer no, I gave path of executable.

Comment: Well guys I solved error1 by myself.The path variables were not correct  there.But still having error 2,someone please help me.

Comment: @TimMeyer ,@Zaiborg : I use Qt 5.0.2 do i need to specify something in build & run->Qt mkspec:.b/s it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Check my Tool Chains:

The important thing is the call of "C:\Program Files...vcvars32.bat" which is called as initialization. This batch file extends the `PATH` variables and does some other things so the calls of `cl.exe` and `link.exe` etc work. Maybe you can manually configure something like that as well. In my case, Qt Creator just auto-detected it and it has always been there.

[image: Tool Chains of Qt Creator]

Note that these settings are for Windows XP 32bit with Visual Studio 2008

Comment: mine is Qt 5.0.2 and have MSVC 2010, and mkspec filed is empty.I think this is causing the error2.What shoul I write here because it is not taking anything by itself.

Comment: `win32-msvc2010` then.. i think.. there must be a folder called like that in %QTDIR%\mkspec

Comment: that also didn't work.I included mkspecs also.what to do know?